# DOM Manipulation by variable with attributes inside array

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5 hyperlinks on my html file:

```
<body>
<a id="link_1" href="">Link 1</a>
<a id="link_2" href="">Link 2</a>
<a id="link_3" href="">Link 3</a>
<a id="link_4" href="">Link 4</a>
<a id="link_5" href="">Link 5</a>
</body>
```

And in my scripts tag I have this array:

```
var attribArr = [innerHTML, href];
```

And I am doing this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < attribArr.length; j++){
       var linkID = 'link_'+i;
       var attribToReplace = attribArr[j];
       document.getElementById(linkID).attribToReplace = 'link_'+i;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: There is zero jQuery here.

Comment: @CertainPerformance edited the tags. Have put the wrong tags. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to set the property name stored in the variable `attribToReplace`

```
document.getElementById(linkID)[attribToReplace] = 'link_'+i;
```

Comment: You saved my life. I'm still learning HTML. I feel dumb for not knowing this. Lol.